Spring Session Redis - always getting could not get resource from pool
The bug
This is the bug I keep getting, when I load my Spring Application:
2024-08-23T00:17:20.005+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port 9090 (http)
2024-08-23T00:17:20.042+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [           main] com.example.bff.BFFApplicationKt         : Started BFFApplicationKt in 7.754 seconds (process running for 8.275)
2024-08-23T00:17:20.071+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [ioEventLoop-5-1] c.example.bff.auth.redis.SessionEvicter  : No sessions found to remove.
2024-08-23T00:17:20.071+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [ioEventLoop-5-1] c.example.bff.auth.redis.SessionEvicter  : Cleanup operation completed.
2024-08-23T00:17:25.823+01:00  WARN 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [oundedElastic-1] o.s.b.a.d.r.RedisReactiveHealthIndicator : Redis health check failed

org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis
Caused by: org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

2024-08-23T00:19:20.054+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [ioEventLoop-5-1] c.example.bff.auth.redis.SessionEvicter  : No sessions found to remove.
2024-08-23T00:19:20.062+01:00  INFO 9758 --- [BFFApplication] [ioEventLoop-5-1] c.example.bff.auth.redis.SessionEvicter  : Cleanup operation completed.

Lettuce Connection Factory
I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. The code is too long to put here, due to Stack Overflow limits (excuse the pun!).
So I've put it here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/3171
This always happens when I load Spring Boot, after about 15s after establishing a connection - but then it abruptly resets. Can someone help?
